# Why some CSS rules work only in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Please go to [this page](http://cosmodent.lemonadestudio.pl/) in Chrome and look at the section **Aktualności** and text:

> Tupacsum Ipsum She nearly gave her life....

Then look at this same URL on Firefox and Opera. Next try to explain to me why this rule: `font: 12px normal 'Lato', 'Times New Roman';` is not working on this both (FF, Opera) as well as on Chrome.

Did I make a mistake somewhere? Or did I use something that works only on Chrome?

---

### Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

### Firefox:

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Looks like you have some specificity issues.. `body #main.home > .bottom .right .top article` seems like an unnecessarily long selector.

Comment: You don't see any difference. Are you also check source? There is no difference too?

Comment: @ferne97 I use LESS and nested rules. I will try put rule some levels up in stylesheet and see what happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is just confused by the generic font attribute's values.  You need to specify more values so it understands where to apply what.

This works fine:

```
body #main.home > .bottom .right .top article {
    font: normal 12px/normal 'Lato', 'Times New Roman';
}
```

The solution from @ferne97, though is likely a better practice to not use as specific of a selector, only works because the font-family is explicitly set instead of using the same generic font attribute.  If you use the simplified selector with the original font attribute values the problem still remains.

Comment: Well you have right. It was by wrong order in font property. I wrote `12px normal 'Lato', 'Times New Roman';` where font-weight (normal) should be first right?

Comment: Often the order can be mixed up and the browsers can still interpret it but not in this case.  The official order, I believe, is: style weight size/line-height family.  See here for details: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

Comment: No official order is in official specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand

Comment: OK cool; it must have just been the browsers not knowing how to interpret the particular line you had, where being more verbose helped to clarify.  Glad it's working with the tweak though.  And having a less specific selector, like @ferne97 mentioned, is a good idea.  The more specific the selector, the more the browser has to process, and the harder it is to override it with later styles.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change it from `body #main.home > .bottom .right .top article` to `.desc p`

```
.desc p {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Times New Roman';
    line-height: normal;
}
```

Be careful when nesting rules when using LESS, you should never really nest more than 3 levels deep. Think of how you would write the actual selector first, then just nest what is needed.

Comment: It works. Wasn't know about this information with 3 levels deep. Can you share with some materials abbuot it?

Comment: In general you want to avoid over qualifying css selectors so you don't run into specificity issues. Because nesting is an easy way to organize in LESS or Sass, it can lead to very long selectors which aren't necessary most of the time. Read over the Qualified selectors section in this article http://csswizardry.com/2012/11/code-smells-in-css/, actually read the whole article, it's pretty good.